# I need help finding the error in this bash script

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I'm attempting to test my code, but I keep getting errors w/ everything I try. I will attach my code and the current error I am receiving. I am unsure what to change or adjust w/o changing the code entirely, and I've tried many different changes. I've gotten so far as downloading the zip file, but it would not download all the files, only 2/3 for some reason, and after some changes, I can not even get back to the downloading. Please help & if possible. I rather that, instead of telling me outright the answer, you tell me which part is wrong and why it is wrong and then, at most, suggest what I should be thinking to make it correct.

This is the current error I am receiving. I have already checked to ensure the files are in the correct directories I'm trying to access and that they can be opened. This is my current code. I've changed it a couple of times and did the rookie mistake of not saving each iteration so I can compare and understand what works and what doesn't

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would suggest running your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Also, since you don’t have a shebang shown are you sure you’re running bash?

Comment: Please post your script as text, not as an image.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in "$targetDirectory"
```

Note that this does NOT iterate over files and directories inside the "target directory", but whatever after the `in`, so with

```
for file in a
```

You get a loop with single iteration in which `$file` would be expanded to `a`, and with

```
for file in a b c
```

You get a loop with three iterations in which `$file` would be expanded to `a`, `b` and `c` respectively.

```
for file in *
```

would probably do what you want, unless there are dotfiles that need to be handled. Also note that `file` doesn't make it iterate over files only, but whatever in the current working path on that single level.

Comment: Note that `for file in *` will fail if files have whitespaces or newline characters in the name. And, depending on what you then do with the files, ones with a leading dash might give problems.

Comment: @doneal24 I don't think leading dash is relevant here since it "might give problems" even when you are not globbing or iterating. (It's not even a shell problem.) As for whitespace, it should work fine as long as you remember to quote `$file` like the OP does when expanding. No idea about newline as I don't recall having bumped into a case as insane as that lol. One thing might (or might not) be relevant here is `IFS`, but either way, I'll leave it to the OP or others to dive into that since that wasn't "the problem" in the original code.

Comment: Try creating a file using `touch -- -rf` then run `for file in *; do rm $file; done` and see what happens. You might not like the results. Less drastic results when using other commands but you'll likely get error messages and undesired results. After dealing with a few hundred users over several hundred servers, I have seen pretty much any file name that is supported under UNIX/Linux. But you're right, this is not a shell problem but how the application handles parameters.

Comment: @doneal24 as you have shown, the solution is to add `--` where necessary / appropriate. I'm aware of the "issue", but again I cannot (or at least, I'm not interested in) cover every potential problem that is not even related to the core of the question.